# How do I use sql to select this

Tags: mysql, sql, continuous

I have the following data:

[image]

and I don't know how to use one sentence to query the continuous value(one = 1) when position is 2.the result should like this:

```
maxCount

   3
```

Comment: Do not include images, its better to add plain data set as text

Comment: You need to do a better job of explaining what you are trying to find here.  It is not clear to me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should elaborate your logic in OP, not the comment above, this will help better, here you can try following sql and check if it's what you want or not:

```
SELECT
    MAX(@cnt := CASE WHEN one = 1 THEN  @cnt + 1 ELSE 0 END) AS maxCount
FROM yourtable
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @cnt := 0 ) t
WHERE `position` = 2
ORDER BY id
```

Also you can check [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b19/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are summing them, use the `SUM` function.

```
SELECT SUM(one) FROM table WHERE position = 2;
```

Otherwise if just counting use the `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE position = 2 AND one = 1
```

If you want a running count, do it in your program, you're asking the database to do something that really belongs in your loop that loads these records.

Comment: He is expecting something else. not count(*)

Comment: wow,I need some time to explain what I really want.
   the data in picture.
  when position = 2, it has six records.
 and if I use "select one from table where position = 2" the result should be "100111"
  and "1" shows four times,but they are not continuous in "100111", it should be 3 times.and the result I want is 3.
   oh,my god,this is so diffcult question to me.hope you guys can understand what I say.lol.